# A Shocking Revelation

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

[image]

---

**Name Who to Shock (Electrically):**

David Ingram
Anne Garcia
Robert Ortiz
Teresa Smith
Edward Vasquez
Elizabeth Nguyen

Comment: TIL the name of a plant in Urdu. `:)`

Comment: @MOehm [Collins Scrabble Words (2019) with definitions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XIFdZukAcDRiDIOgR_rHpICrrgJbLBxV/view)

Comment: Oh, I'm not questioning the validity of the word. I came from a different direction anyway. I just wanted to show my progress with an oblique comment. A cool puzzle, by the way, but I can't wrap it up. (I'm not asking for a hint; just putting my towel on the "halfway there" deckchair.)

Comment: @MOehm Glad you are enjoying it. Everything you need to solve it is there in the post. I used my reply to your comment to post that word list to give solvers an idea of what I consider a legit word for the purposes of this puzzle. It is not important enough to include in the puzzle itself though.

Comment: Yes, I had a nice aha moment and I may have had another one just now ...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The electrical shock goes to ...

> ... poor **ANNE GARCIA**.

The answers to the seven rebuses are:

> **COLLEGE** — **LEG** in **COLE**
>  **SETBACK** — **SET** and **BACK**
>  **THISTLE** — **[STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Louis_Lambert_International_Airport)** International Airport in Ton **[THIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ton_Thie)**
>  **KLEENEX** — Stan **[LEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee)** in **[K'NEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%27Nex)** toys
>  **BASTILE** — **[TIL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/til)**, a word for sesame in Urdu, in **BASE**
>  **ETHANOL** — **[ET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.T._the_Extra-Terrestrial)** and **[HAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_Solo)** Solo and **OL**, a suffix for organic compounds with an OH group*
>  **ANTIGEN** — **ANTI** (crossed out sign) and **GEN** (generation)
>
>  * I'm not quite sure about the OH group, after all, the **OL** is already right there in Solo. Anyway, it must be ethanol.

These answers ...

> ... all have seven letters. They can be rearranged to form a **word square** where the same words can be read horizontally and vertically:
>
>      `S` `E` `T` `B` `A` `C` `K`
>      `E` `T` `H` `A` `N` `O` `L`
>      `T` `H` `I` `S` `T` `L` `E`
>      `B` `A` `S` `T` `I` `L` `E`
>      `A` `N` `T` `I` `G` `E` `N`
>      `C` `O` `L` `L` `E` `G` `E`
>      `K` `L` `E` `E` `N` `E` `X`

The list of names ...

> ... gives another hint: The first letters of the names spell **DI AG RO TS EV EN** or "Diag. Rot 7", where diag. presumably means "diagonal".
>
>  The diagonal of our word square reads **STITGGX**.
>
>  Applying Rot 7, that is shifting every letter by seven places in the alphabet and wrapping from Z to A if needed, we get **ZAPANNE**.

This is clearly ...

> ... an instruction to **zap Anne**.

Comment: Nicely done, and well-summarized. Are you saying that instead of the hydroxyl group it is better to put -S-O, removing the letters from Solo to produce the OL? Also, wouldn't "til" also be an English word if it is in the Scrabble dictionary? (not that I've ever used that word. :) ) Also, not necessary for the solve, but there's a clue on which diagonal to look at.

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting that one rebus is better than the other; I just got stuck there for a little, but the overall property of the words cleared that up soon. The suffix for alocohols can be found in dictionaries, so that's fair. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/til) agrees with you that "til" is an English word, but it's hard to find even if you have identified the plant via reverse image search. I found it from filling in the blanks in the word square, of course. You can get away with a lot if you have a good mechanism to confirm the answers.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Also, the capital letters in "Name Who to Shock (Electrically):" were intended to indicate which diagonal of the word square.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. I just assumed it would be the "main diagonal", _Aii_.